# what are $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle 2 \rangle$??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Suppose modulo 17, $\langle 2 \rangle=\{1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16\}$ since

$2^1 \equiv 2 \mod 17$

$2^2 \equiv 4 \mod 17$

$2^3 \equiv 8 \mod 17$

$2^4 \equiv 16 \mod 17$

$2^5 \equiv 32 \equiv 15 \mod 17$

$2^6 \equiv 15 \times 2 \equiv 13 \mod 17$

$2^7 \equiv 13 \times 2 \equiv 9 \mod 17$

$2^8 \equiv 9 \times 2 \equiv 1 \mod 17$

Now I want to know the quotient groups  $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle 2 \rangle$

These are $\langle 2 \rangle=\{1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16\}$ itself and $\{3,5,6,7,10,11,12,14\}$.

The latter part is the rest of $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*$ except  $\langle 2 \rangle$

How do we find the latter part? In this example  the number of the quotient groups are 2, it seems simple.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the order of your quotient group? How many groups exists of such an order?

Comment: yeah i know the each order $|(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*|=16$ and $|\langle 2 \rangle|$=8. So the number of cosets are 2. Quotient groups are cyclic group $\langle 2 \rangle $itself and 3$\langle 2 \rangle$. I want to know where the 3 comes from

Comment: @zorutic: Why 3? The number of cosets is the order.

Comment: I know the order of the quotient groups. I want to know the way how to determine all the cosets.

Comment: @zorutic: Directly. By definition.

Comment: Could you show me the definition?

Comment: @zorutic: Use your textbook or Google.

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's theorem, you know that 
$$|G|:=|(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle\bar{2}\rangle|=\frac{|(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*|}{|\langle\bar{2}\rangle|}.$$
As you have shown, $|\langle\bar{2}\rangle|=8,$ so $|G|=\frac{17-1}{8}=2.$ As you know too that $\langle\bar{2}\rangle\in G,$ it follows that 
$$G=\{\langle\bar{2}\rangle,(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*-\langle\bar{2}\rangle\}.$$

Comment: I agree with your solution. But your idea can be used only for the case when the order of quotient group is 2. What is the more general solution???

Comment: @zorutic: To get more general solution you should ask more general question.

Comment: For arbitrary integers instead of $17$ and $2$ (the first one being prime) ? As Corvus said, I think that re writting your question can bring you better answers than ours !

Comment: Yes. In particular, I think  $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^* - \langle 2 \rangle$ is not a  correct solution. It follows the correct result since the order is 2.

Comment: As the elements of the quotient groups are a partition of the initial group, and that here you know there are only two elements and one of them is known, I think there are not so many choices for the second one. Edit : You wanted to say for the general case ? In this case I agree with you, but try to ask a new question or to reformulate this one to make appear the general case more directly :)

Answer (score 1):

It means any unit in $(\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z)^*$ is either a power of $2$ or $3\times$ a power of $2$. Note the square of each element in the latter part is a power of $2$.

Also, observe that, $\langle 2\rangle\simeq \mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$ (the additive group), and  $(\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z)^*$ is a cyclic group, isomorphic to the additive group   $ \mathbf Z/16\mathbf Z$, so the multiplicative quotient group   $(\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z)^*/\langle 2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the additive quotient group
$$ (\mathbf Z/16\mathbf Z)/(\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z)\simeq\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$$
by the third isomorphism theorem.