# Efficient solution finding quotient group and is there generator in quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*/\langle 11 \rangle$??

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My question is two-fold.

- How can we find quotient group  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*/\langle 11 \rangle$ efficiently??

  I have an answer but am not sure whether it is correct or not.

  Clearly, the order of quotient group is

  $\frac{|\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*|}{|\langle 11 \rangle|}=\frac{\phi(15)}{2}=\frac{8}{2}=4$

  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*=\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$

  $\langle 11 \rangle=\{ 1,11\}$

  Since $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$ is a multiplicative group, one can try $a\langle 11 \rangle$ where $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$

  I have found that $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*/\langle 11 \rangle=\{  \{1,11\},\{2,7\},\{4,14\},\{8,13\} \}$  without duplicate.

  But I did naive way that I calculate all the elements of $a\langle 11 \rangle$ where $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$ ,and removed duplications.

  How can we find them efficiently without all search??
- What is the generator in that quotient group?

  Is there any generator in this quotient group?

  I know all the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$ are generators with order 2 or 4 mod 15 except 1.

  One said 2 is a generator with order 2 in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*/\langle 11 \rangle$.

  What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Compare also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931516/what-are-mathbbz-17-mathbbz-langle-2-rangle).

Comment: no solution there

Answer (score 3):

Use the Chinese remainder theorem to get $ \mathbf Z/15 \cong \mathbf Z/3 \times \mathbf Z/5 $, and pass to the multiplicative groups to get $ (\mathbf Z/15)^{\times} \cong \mathbf Z/2 \oplus \mathbf Z/4 $, where the RHS is written additively. To describe the quotient group, we have to find where $ 11 $ is sent by the isomorphism between these groups. The map $ \mathbf Z/15 \to \mathbf Z/3 \times \mathbf Z/5 $ sends $ 11 \to (2, 1) $, and since $ 2 $ is a primitive root modulo $ 3 $ the image of $ 11 $ under the isomorphism $ (\mathbf Z/15)^{\times} \to \mathbf Z/2 \oplus \mathbf Z/4 $ is $ (1, 0) $. The quotient is therefore cyclic of order $ 4 $, with a generator being given by $ (0, 1) $, which turns out to be $ 7 $ once you chase it in the isomorphisms.